# Inserting date in oracle database using Php

Tags: php, oracle, oracle10g

I am trying to insert date in Oracle 10g using php. This is my query:

```
$dat='1989-10-21';
$did="0011";
$nam="George";
$sql= "insert into table (did, name, date_of_birth) values (:did,:nam, TO_DATE(:dat,’YYYY-MM-DD’))";
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':did', $did);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':nam', $nam);
    oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':dat', $dat);
    $result = oci_execute($stmt);
```

But it is giving me the following error:

> oci_execute() [function.oci-execute]: ORA-00911: invalid character in
>   C:\Apache2.2\htdocs\new2.php on line 14

I have tried running it without binding but its still not working. I checked it on sql plus its working fine. Please help

Comment: maybe it's because of the wrong quote characters (`’YYYY-MM-DD’`) - should be `('YYYY-MM-DD')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to quote the first param when use to_date,at least I use it like this:

```
$date = '2013-11-11';

 $sql = "select t.* from my_table t where create_date>to_date('". $date ."','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')";
```

Perhaps it can give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks, That works....though now am wondering t=why binding the date doesnt work any idea?